# Is Amazon S3 versioning really a reasonable backup options?

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

I am in the process of moving my web apps project storage to S3 and I am wondering if S3 versioning is really a good way to handle backups of the data or is there some better way? If the files were all to be deleted or corrupted in some way is it possible and easy to restore an entire bucket using the versioning? If so how? If not, what would be a better backup option for S3?

Answer (score 7):

Versioning is a great feature, and it should absolutely be used if possible. Having versioning enabled (and using appropriately-provisioned access keys) can save you from all manner of issues.

But.

Versioning won't protect you from;

1. Loss of control of your AWS account,
2. S3 downtime or widespread corruption,
3. Other similar act-of-god type issues.

You *need* to have backups of your data outside of S3, even if that's an external hard drive that you run `$ aws s3 sync` against a couple of times a day. Having a backup-of-last-resort is very simple to do, and is very inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

No, a backup strategy for off service is required regardless of the service in question.  Aside from the potential for service side corruption, account issues can cause unrecoverable issues.